# Periodically sending api request in the background and receiving the result as notification

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to make an application exactly like the title. Every 5 or 15 minutes in the background, I will send a request to the api which I made and send a notification to my phone according to the results.

I used the react-native-notifications and react-native-background-timer plugin but when I lock my phone or close the app, notifications are not received. (IOS)

I struggled for a week, I couldn't do it.
I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: You can't execute requests that frequently in the background on iOS. Polling isn't very efficient for battery or network. A much better approach is to have some server somewhere that checks the api and sends a push notification when appropriate

Comment: @Paulw11 I need to know php to achieve this, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use node.js or python or any number of languages. You don't need a web server to do this. You could use aws lambda or azure functions or.....